# How to Customize Wp Default Title and a prefix

Tags: headers, wp-title

This code snippet shows (prefix) category Name first before the Post title (Very right).

E.g

- Music: %Post_title%
- Video: %post_title%
- Lyrics: %post_title%
- News: %post_title%
- Lifstyle: %Post_title%.

Now the problem is,  I wanted to show this on a very specific category(Music & Video) alone and not all categories...

E.g on category Music & Video alone.

Then any other post from any other category will not show any Prefix at all...

Below is the code snippet:

```php
add_filter('wp_title', function ($title) {


if (is_single()) {
    $categories = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
    // Assuming the post has many categories will take the first
    $category = reset($categories);
    return $category->name .': '.$title; 
}
return $title;
}


);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this code.

```
add_filter('wp_title', 'custom_title');
function custom_title($title) {
    if(is_single()) {
        $category = get_the_category(get_the_ID());
        if(!empty($category)){
            $categories = array('music','video');
            if(in_array($category[0]->slug,$categories)){
                return $category[0]->name.': '.$title;
            }
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tanmaypatel